# Struggling to solve differential equation once integrated

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is this:
A body falling vertically though the air has speed $v$ at time $t$, related by the
differential equation

$\frac{\delta v}{\delta t} = g - cv$

where g and c are positive constants. Given that $v = v_{0}$ when $t = 0$, solve
this equation to find $v$ at time $t$.

I have tried to separate it and integrate both sides and have been left with

$-\frac{\ln \left | g - cv \right |}{c} + v_{0} = t$

My question is am I correct in separating and integrating it in this way and if so, is it correct to call the constant of integration $v_{0}$ or is the $v_{0}$ in the question referring to something different. If I am correct thus far, any hints as to how I can finish solving this would be greatly appreciated as the paper has no mark scheme associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see... you started with
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=g-cv$$
Separated variables and integrated to get
$$-\frac{\ln|g-cv|}c=t+C_1$$
Then you want to apply initial conditions
$$-\frac{\ln|g-cv_0|}c=C_1$$
So now you should have
$$-\frac{\ln|g-cv|}c+\frac{\ln|g-cv_0|}c=\frac1c\ln\left(\frac{g-cv_0}{g-cv}\right)=t$$
$$\frac{g-cv_0}{g-cv}=e^{ct}$$
And we can solve for $v$ to get
$$v=\frac{cv_0+g\left(e^{ct}-1\right)}{ce^{ct}}=\frac gc+\left(v_0-\frac gc\right)e^{-ct}$$

Comment: Thank-you, that's helped a lot!